# Prolog - recursive list building

Tags: prolog

for a program I'm writing I need to make a list of lists, with pairs of numbers representing a product and sum of 2 given numbers.

For now I have a function which I can specify how many times I want to add a list to the list, which will be expanded with the full functionality later.

Here's what I have:

```
s1(0, X).
s1(Q, X) :-
    N is Q - 1,
    multiply(2, 3, Y),
    A = Y ,
    add(2, 3, Z),
    B = Z,
    addToEnd([A], [B], X),
    s1(N,X).

multiply(A, B, C):-
    C is A * B.

add(A, B, C) :-
    C is A + B.

addToEnd([], L, L).
addToEnd([H|T], L2, [H|L3]) :-
    addToEnd(T, L2, L3).
```

However, when I run `s1(2,X)` for example, I get `[6,5]` returned, then nothing else, it just hangs. When I run `s1(0,X)`, i get `true`, then `false` when I hit `;`

Can anyone help me with this? I can't see what I'm doing wrong, I feel like it should work!

To clarify how I feel this should work: 
I call `s1(2,X).` 
`N = 1`, `[6,5]` added to list in `X([[6,5]])` 
`s1(1,X).`
`N=0`, `[6,5]` added to the list in `X ([[6,5],[6,5]])` 
`s1(0,X).` 
`X = [[6,5],[6,5]]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So, there are many things to say here. First and foremost, as in most declarative languages, a variable cannot really change value.

What that means is that `X = 1.` will unify `1` to `X` as you'd expect, but if you add `X = 2.` after that in your query (`X = 1, X = 2.`), Prolog will say `false`. The reason behind that is that you cannot unify `1` with `2` and that `X` has truly become `1`, therefore `X` cannot be unified to `2`.

Though, and that differs from Haskell, Ocaml and the like, you can bind partially a variable, as in `X = h(Y).`. You'll then be able to further unify it `X = h(a(Z)).`, while you couldn't in the languages mentionned earlier (where a variable is really just an alias for a value).

Why does he tell me all that you wonder? Well, that's your main problem here. You first bind `X` to `[6, 5]`, and then expect to further bind it to some other things. Once a variable is ground (ie does not contain any free variable inside itself), you cannot ever change its value again.

So here your recursion won't do anything but eventually prove `X` false. Here it doesn't however since you end up calling `addToEnd/3` with the same arguments each time (`[6]`, `[5]` and `[6, 5]`).

That being said, let's look at how we could improve your code.

First, a remark:

```
multiply(2, 3, Y),
A = Y ,
add(2, 3, Z),
B = Z,
addToEnd([A], [B], X),
```

can be written

```
multiply(2, 3, Y),
add(2, 3, Z),
addToEnd([Y], [Z], X),
```

without any loss of information since you do not use `A` and `B` again.

Now, let's forget about `addToEnd/3` for a moment and think about what you want.

If you enter `s1(0, Q)`, do you really want `Q` to stay free? Because that's what you state at the moment. It'd make more sense to bind `Q` to `[]` in that case. Plus, that'll make a good recursive base case as you'll soon see.

```
s1(0, []).
```

is a shortcut to say

```
s1(0, Q) :- Q = [].
```

since Prolog does unification in clause heads (the part before `:-`).

Then, I'll cheat a little but it'll just be to stay clear. You could state that when going from `s1(4, Q)` to `s1(5, Q)` you expect Q to hold one more value of some calculus.

Here, we could state that as follows:

```
s1(N, [SomeCalculus|Q]) :-
    PreviousN is N - 1,
    s1(PreviousN, Q).
```

Now, we just have to give a value to `SomeCalculus`:

```
s1(N, [SomeCalculus|Q]) :-
    PreviousN is N - 1,
    X is 2 * 3,
    Y is 2 + 3,
    SomeCalculus = [X, Y],
    s1(PreviousN, Q).
```

or, if you followed correctly, we could directly write:

```
s1(N, [[X, Y]|Q]) :-
    PreviousN is N - 1,
    X is 2 * 3,
    Y is 2 + 3,
    s1(PreviousN, Q).
```

So the complete program would be:

```
s1(0, []).
s1(N, [[X, Y]|Q]) :-
    PreviousN is N - 1,
    X is 2 * 3,
    Y is 2 + 3,
    s1(PreviousN, Q).
```

Now, if you test that, you might remark that the program loops just as yours when you hit the `;` key. That's because Prolog thinks the second clause can apply to `0`
 too.

So let's edit the program once more:

```
s1(0, []).
s1(N, [[X, Y]|Q]) :-
    N > 0,
    PreviousN is N - 1,
    X is 2 * 3,
    Y is 2 + 3,
    s1(PreviousN, Q).
```

Now everything is fine.

I hope this'll help you to get a better understanding of how to build a proper predicate through recursion. I didn't spend much time correcting your `addToEnd/3` predicate because my rambling about variables should already have told you a lot about what's wrong about it.

Comment: Thanks very much for this, it really helps. Apologies for What I'm sure are basic errors in my code, I'm new to prolog, and coming from c, java and the like, it's a very different way of thinking.

Comment: @XavierNuquos: You do not need to apologize for trying to learn here, after all that's what SO is about. Come up with more questions if you struggle!

Comment: Thanks Mog, as it happens I've made some advances with this, but I'm at another roadblock, so I should be adding another question soon :)