# Building lists recursively with values returned from other predicates in Prolog

Tags: recursion, prolog

Disclaimer: this is a school assignment.

New-ish to Prolog and have a decent understanding of the basics. Assignment is to differentiate polynomials. This part is not the problem. I have devised an algorithm that works and implemented it in Prolog to my satisfaction. At this point, calling my diff_term predicate results in a properly differentiated polynomial term every time.

However, when I pass a full polynomial to my diff_poly predicate, whose job it is to parse the terms, pass them for differentiation, and recollect them into a list to return tot he user, things break down. My problem is recursively adding the returned polynomial terms (lists) to the fully-differentiated polynomial (another list). I have consulted numerous related Stackoverflow questions, finding this one particularly useful:

[Prolog - recursive list building](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10057760/prolog-recursive-list-building)

I read it thoroughly and re-created the same program in order to understand it. The main difference, however, is that in my situation the values I am adding to the list are being returned by other predicates as opposed to being created within the same predicate as the list is being built in.

The following code consists of my `diff_poly` predicate, which then calls `diff_term`. `diff_term` then calls numerous other homemade predicates to perform the algorithm; however, none of that is an issue, and differentiation, as mentioned above, works well. You can likely understand what my algorithmic approach is by predicate names alone.

The `diff_poly` predicate is the only `diff_poly` that exists; there are no base cases or other variations, as I am able to assume (as per assignment specifications) that all input will be consistently and validly formatted. There are, however, a few other `diff_term` predicates for dealing with variations on term contents, all of which return proper term derivatives.

If I call `diff_poly` as is, I get 'false' as my return. If I comment out the last line of that predicate and uncomment the one previous to it, I get exactly one differentiated term returned to me, which is expected as their is no recursive call, and proves that the call to/return from `diff_term` works.

Essentially I just need some direction on how to build the list to be returned. I've tried appending, inserting, etc, but I think the head matching strategy (outlined in the question above) is the way to go, but that I am implementing something incorrectly. Any insight is appreciated.

```
% differentiates a polynomial with respect to given variable
% polynomials are parsed into terms, and terms are passed to diff_term
diff_poly([Term | Rest], DiffVar, DiffedPoly) :-
    diff_term(Term, DiffVar, DiffedTerm),
%    DiffedPoly = DiffedTerm.
    diff_poly(Rest, DiffVar, [DiffedTerm | DiffedPoly]).


% term is a coefficient and at least one var/exp pair in its member variable list
% term includes occurrence of variable to differentiate with respect to
diff_term([Coef | Rest], DiffVar, Return) :-
    flatten(Rest, FlatList),
    member(DiffVar, FlatList),
    index_of(FlatList, DiffVar, Index),
    nth1(Index, FlatList, Exp),
    Exp > 1, NewCoef is Coef * Exp, NewExp is Exp - 1,
    remove_at(FlatList, Index, RemoveList),
    insert_at(NewExp, RemoveList, Index, InsertList),
    split_varlist(InsertList, DoneList),
    Return = [NewCoef | DoneList], !.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your `diff_term` is good (which you can test modularly at the Prolog prompt), let's look at `diff_poly`:

```
diff_poly([Term | Rest], DiffVar, DiffedPoly) :-
    diff_term(Term, DiffVar, DiffedTerm),
%    DiffedPoly = DiffedTerm.
    diff_poly(Rest, DiffVar, [DiffedTerm | DiffedPoly]).
```

This clause says that *`DiffedPoly` is the polynomial `[Term|Rest]` differentiated with respect to `DiffVar`*. Sounds good so far.

Your first expression within the clause says, *`DiffedTerm` is `Term` differentiated with respect to `DiffVar`. That sounds good, too.

The next commented line says to unify `DiffedPoly` with `DiffedTerm`. This would no longer make sense since the fully differentiated polynomial would, in general not be just the differentiated term (unless, of course, the polynomial only had one term). Let's leave that commented out.

Finally, we have:

```
diff_poly(Rest, DiffVar, [DiffedTerm | DiffedPoly])
```

This says, *The result of differentiating the rest of the polynomial (without the first term) with respect to `DiffVar` is the first term differentiated with respect to `DiffVar` (i.e., `DiffTerm`) followed by the fully differentiated polynomial (`DiffedPoly`)*. If you think about that, it doesn't make sense. It's written as if you changed what `DiffedPoly` really means. This query should be expressing, *The fully differentiated polynomial (`DiffedPoly`) is the differentiation of the initial term (`DiffedTerm`) followed by the differentiation of the rest of the polynomial (differentiation of `Rest` with respect to `DiffVar`)*. Translate this last description into Prolog, then you'll be almost there.

Almost... that's because there needs to be a base case to the recursion. What happens on an empty polynomial? You would need also to add a `diff_poly([], <something>, <something>)` for that case.

Comment: There we go. That solves it perfectly for me. Thanks for talking it out and getting my mind wrapped around it properly. Cheers!

Comment: @carofthecdr glad you figured it out. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should change the 'direction' of information flow, and add a base case.
Something simple like this should work

```
% we need this one, to match when Rest become an empty list
diff_poly([], _DiffVar, []).

diff_poly([Term | Rest], DiffVar, [DiffedTerm | DiffedPoly]) :-
    diff_term(Term, DiffVar, DiffedTerm),
    diff_poly(Rest, DiffVar, DiffedPoly).
```

This list processing pattern can be simplified by maplist/3 introduction

```
diff_poly(TermList, DiffVar, DiffedList) :-
    maplist(diff_poly_(DiffVar), TermList, DiffedList).

% since maplist appends lists'elements to argument list, we need a service predicate
% otherwise, and better, a swap of diff_term arguments could do
diff_poly_(DiffVar, Term, Diffed) :-
    diff_term(Term, DiffVar, Diffed).
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I had actually gotten underway with suggestions from the first answer as soon as it came in. My result looks surprisingly like yours (the on without maplist). Cheers!